# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment - how can i identify and remove this ? or do debug in this case?

Tags: python-3.x

I have made a proper for loop still But I am getting the below error.

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment

How do I fix the above error ?

```
import numpy as np
n=0
import math
def polygonPerimeter(x,y):
    for i in range(np.size(x)):
        n = n +math.sqrt((x[i]-x[i+1])**2+(y[i]-y[i+1])**2)
    P=n
    return P

print(polygonPerimeter(np.array([1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 1]), np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5])))
```

Comment: define your variable n = 0 inside of the function, NOTE: your range is false, use for i in range(np.size(x)-1) or you will get an aerror out of range

Comment: I change it , but i am getting wrong answer i think , even though my code is correct , i think jsut because of (np.size(x)-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python variables always work under two kinds of scope - Global and Local. In your case, `n=0` is globally defined variable. You cannot directly access it in a function. You can use `global` keyword for that purpose.

The following code will work, I've tested it:

```
import numpy as np
n=0
import math
def polygonPerimeter(x,y):
    global n
    # np.size(x) returns value 7 
    for i in range(np.size(x)-1):
        n = n +math.sqrt((x[i]-x[i+1])**2+(y[i]-y[i+1])**2)
    P=n
    return P

print(polygonPerimeter(np.array([1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 1]), np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5])))
```

You can go by this method, or you can define the variable `n=0` locally inside the function. And inside for loop, you have `x[i+1]` which will fail for the last element in your numpy array, so I've changed the for loop range to `np.size(x)-1`.